# $cordovaLocalNotification trigger event stop working when $cordovaLocalNotification update

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, ngcordova, localnotification

I have an abstract controller with a simple scheduled notification showing data from a resolved promise every minute

```
$ionicPlatform.ready(function () {
    postsToShow.notifUnread().then(function(data){
        $cordovaLocalNotification.schedule({
            id: 1,
            title: "Title",
            text: "Data "+data,
            every: "minute"
        });

        $rootScope.$on('$cordovaLocalNotification:trigger', function(notification) {
            postsToShow.notifUnread().then(function(data2){
                console.log(data2+' 2');
                $cordovaLocalNotification.update({
                    id: 1,
                    title: "Title 2",
                    text: "Data "+data2,
                    every: "minute"
                });
            });
        });
    });
});
```

When I call `$cordovaLocalNotification:trigger` event without the `$cordovaLocalNotification.update` it works fine, new data appears on the console, but after I insert the `$cordovaLocalNotification.update`, the notification is updated and repeatedly shown as expected but the `$cordovaLocalNotification:trigger` is not called any more. Why is this?

Edit: Using Android emulator live reload for testing the notifications.